# Populate numerous elements with same class using ajax call

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

This is a brand new concept to me, so I really need some help.  I'm trying to populate all  tags with the class "WorkstationCount" by using an ajax call to a web service.  I have confirmed the webservice, as called below, is functioning and returning a proper integer.  However, the HTML is never being changed.  Currently with the code below I don't receive any console errors either.  I'm sure I'm doing this way wrong, but I tried :)

```
$('.WorkstationCount').html(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'details.svc/getWorkstationCounts',
        type: 'GET',
        data: { 'packageid': $(this).attr('id') },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (count) {
            return count.d;
        },
        error: function (a, b, c) {
            $('.Toast').html('Error Retreiving Workstation Count!');
        }
    });
});
```

**ATTEMPT TO CLARIFY**

```
 <span class="WorkstationCount" id="1"></span>
 <span class="WorkstationCount" id="2"></span>
 <span class="WorkstationCount" id="3"></span>
```

So each span should have a different result...  the ajax call is made using the element id, then it should modify the content of the span based on that result

Comment: The value returned from the `success` callback is not the value returned by `$.ajax()`. Also, you can **always** use `this.id` in place of `$(this).attr('id')` so long as `this` is a reference to a DOM element.

Comment: @Scott I edited my answer below so it works on each `'WorkstationCount'`

Comment: It's beautiful, but I get a weird error now :)  (below)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ah, after reading your comments I see your problem. You want to send along the id for each element n the data and make a separate ajax request for every `WorkstationCount`:

```
$('.WorkstationCount').each(function(i, val){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'details.svc/getWorkstationCounts',
        type: 'GET',
        data: { 'packageid': this.id },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: (function(el){
                return function (count) {
                    $(el).html(count.d);
                };
            })(this),
        error: function (a, b, c) {
            $('.Toast').html('Error Retreiving Workstation Count!');
        }
    });
});
```

PS `this.id` is a faster way of writing `$(this).attr('id');` since it doesn't rely on a jQuery object and `attr()`

Comment: Yes, exactly!  Sorry it didn't make sense.  With this code I am getting an error: "Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'createDocumentFragment'   jquery-1.5.1.min.js:16

Comment: @Scott Try it again. I think I fixed that. Here is a test using ajax which just returns the html passed to it after a delay: http://jsfiddle.net/rvYFh/

Comment: Awesome!  I wish I could give you 10 upvotes.  :)

Thanks so much for the answer and for understanding the question ;)

Answer (score 1):

You have to update `.WorkstationCount`'s html from within the success function:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'details.svc/getWorkstationCounts',
    type: 'GET',
    data: { 'packageid': $(this).attr('id') },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (count) {
        $('.WorkstationCount').html(count.d);
    },
    error: function (a, b, c) {
        $('.Toast').html('Error Retreiving Workstation Count!');
    }
});
```

Comment: The problem is there can be multiple spans with the class "WorkstationCount", so in your example how does it know which to modify on the success event???

Comment: It modifies them all. Is this not what you want?

Comment: It makes them all 0 because `count.d` is 0. What do you expect it to do?

Comment: no... countd on the first one is 176, on the second one it is 8, on the third one it is 12...

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('.WorkstationCount').html(function () {
$this = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        url: 'details.svc/getWorkstationCounts',
        type: 'GET',
        data: { 'packageid': $(this).attr('id') },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (count) {
            $this.html(count.d);
        },
        error: function (a, b, c) {
            $('.Toast').html('Error Retreiving Workstation Count!');
        }
    });
});
```